React cookies not being saved or sent to backend after login authenticated
I have created a login form in React, to do basic authentication. But, it appears that the cookies (credentials) are not being saved by the React frontend at all. I was given the impression that "withCredentials: true" would automatically save my cookies, but after login, when I type document.cookie into my JavaScript console, it does nothing (returns '').
So basically, all this app does is set isAuthenticated to true after login, and vice versa on logout, and allows you to see other page content just because it says it's authenticated. It's definitely getting the OK from the backend and acting based on that (for example, it'll actually fail and not set isAuthenticated to true if you get the credentials wrong), but it's not saving  any sort of credentials or cookies when the login happens.
Does anyone know why this might be happening? I don't think it is because of my backend, which is why I didn't post it here; I think I've been looking in the wrong place. Could there be something wrong with my React app itself?
I have painstakingly tried so many different things—mostly in the backend because I didn't initially realize this was a frontend issue—to no avail.
Below is my React code. This is pared down as much as possible.
My App.jsx:
// ./App.jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DataForm from './components/TestItemForm';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

function App() {

  // Check localStorage to see if the user is authenticated
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')
  );

  // Handle successful login by updating state and storing in localStorage
  const handleLoginSuccess = () => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'true'); // Save authentication status in localStorage
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Cookies:', document.cookie);
  }, []);
  
  // Handle logout, clear state and localStorage
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('http://localhost:5000/logout', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      localStorage.removeItem('isAuthenticated'); // Remove authentication status from localStorage
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Logout failed');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Pare-Down App</h1>
      {
        isAuthenticated
        ?
        <>
          <DataForm />
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Log Out</button>
        </>
        :
        <LoginForm onLoginSuccess={handleLoginSuccess} />
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default App;

My LoginForm.jsx:
// ./components/LoginForm.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const LoginForm = ({ onLoginSuccess }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [attempts, setAttempts] = useState(0);
  const [lockedOut, setLockedOut] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (lockedOut) return;

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        withCredentials: true,
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setError(null);
        onLoginSuccess();
      } else {
        setAttempts((prev) => prev + 1);
        setError('Username or password was incorrect');
        if (attempts >= 4) {
          setLockedOut(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setLockedOut(false);
            setAttempts(0);
          }, 180000); // 3 minutes
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      {lockedOut && <p>You have been locked out for 3 minutes due to too many failed attempts.</p>}
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Username:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit" disabled={lockedOut}>Log In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;


The problem is likely coming from how you're sending the credentials option in your fetch request. withCredentials: true is typically used to send cookies with your request when using axios but with fetch you use the credentials property which can take 3 different values: include, omit, same-site. See the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
Ideally, if you want cookies to be sent along with your request, you will need to adjust your login api call in the handleSubmit function:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (lockedOut) return;

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        credentials: "include",
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setError(null);
        onLoginSuccess();
      } else {
        setAttempts((prev) => prev + 1);
        setError('Username or password was incorrect');
        if (attempts >= 4) {
          setLockedOut(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setLockedOut(false);
            setAttempts(0);
          }, 180000); // 3 minutes
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  };

Setting credentials: "include" allows the http-only cookie to be sent and received.
It's worthy of mentioning that http-only cookies cannot be retrieved in the browser. Therefore, typing document.cookie will not output the http-only cookie. However, you can view it in the list of cookies saved in the browser.
